# AWS CLI error while running command from Golang

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-s3

I am trying to run aws command using Golang's command function in `os/exec` package. But it gives error on doing so.

**command**: `aws s3 cp SOURCE_DIR s3://BUCKET_NAME/TARGET_DIR --recursive`

**error**: `Unable to locate credentials`

But credentials are set as `shared configuration file`. Please guide me what I am doing wrong here and how it can be resolved.

Comment: Why are you wanting to call the AWS CLI instead of using the [AWS SDK for Go](https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/)?

Comment: AWS credentials are normally stored in `~/.aws/credentials` -- is the Go app running as a user that has this credentials file?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I am using AWS CLI because I need to copy all the object in a directory rather than copying a single object. Also the credentials file is with a different user and the directory which is being copied is with different user. can this be the issue ?

Comment: If the credentials file is not in your home directory, then it won't be found. That is likely why you are receiving the error. I'm not sure what you mean by "the directory which is being copied is with different user".

Comment: "the directory which is being copied is with different user" means credentials file is with "myuser" and directory that I need to copy is with "root" user. But I have credentials file inside home directory.  And I am running the go app as a service on ubuntu.

Comment: The "go app as a service" will run as a user, possibly the root user. Whichever user that is needs the credentials file in their `~/.aws/credentials` file inside their home directory. Alternatively, credentials can be passed via Environment Variables.

Comment: I have ~/.aws/credentials file inside $HOME directory. The go app which is running as service is also located in $HOME. The service is running by root and the credentials file is present with myuser. I am not able to understand what I need to do to fix this issue ?

Comment: If the service is being run by root, then the credentials should be in `/users/root/.aws/credentials`.

Comment: Thanks man, I changed the service user to myuser and it worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the Go program is run with the right user, try and execute instead `aws configure list`

As explained in [this thread](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-locate-credentials-error/), you will see *how* your credentials are configured:

- config file
- environment variable
- instance profile
- or... not at all, in the context of your Go runtime session.

> Also the credentials file is with a different user and the directory which is being copied is with different user. can this be the issue ?

Yes, that is the point of this answer: double-check what your Go program sees during its execution, in term of environment variable (like `$HOME`).

Comment: Thanks VonC for you reply. But I have already check this article. and my configuration is set to shared configuration file, which I have already mentioned in the question.

Comment: @Amandeepkaur True, but did you test that command in your Go program, to check the configuration is detected (again, in the context of the go runtime session)?

Comment: Yes, aws configure list is returning that no credentials are set. I have already credentials file but in the run time go is unable to find that, right ? But how to fix this ?

Comment: @Amandeepkaur One solution is to make sure the Go service is run as your user, not as root, in order to inherit the same environment variables as your current user.